# How to dispatch to Reducer before React renders component?

Tags: reactjs

React newcomer here.

I'm loading Astronomy Picture of the Day in a component using a loading spinner.
I want the page to get data every time I call it from navbar but it's flashing old data before showing the spinner.

How to avoid this behavior? I don't want to use ComponentWillMount because it's deprecated and I'm using functions.

The component code:

```
import { useEffect, useContext } from 'react'
import { getApod } from '../context/nasa/NasaActions'
import NasaContext from '../context/nasa/NasaContext'
import Spinner from './layout/Spinner'

function Apod() {
  const {loading, apod, dispatch} = useContext(NasaContext)
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({type: 'SET_LOADING'})
    const getApodData = async() => {
      const apodData = await getApod()
      dispatch({type: 'SET_APOD', payload: apodData})
    }
    getApodData()
  }, [dispatch])

  const {
    title,
    url,
    explanation,
  } = apod

  if (loading) { return <Spinner /> }
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{title}</h2>
      <img src={url} className='apod' alt='apod'/>
      <p>{explanation}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Apod
```

Thanks for your time.

Edit: I deleted the repository. It's already answared correctly.

Comment: Why you need to use useContext here?

Comment: Studying purposes. This is not a product, just a sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you another solution to keep your navbar clean.

You can declare an instance variable `loaded` using the `useRef` hook. This variable will be initialized to false and set to true as soon as the apod is dispatched to your store.

```
import { useContext, useRef } from 'react'

function Apod() {
  const {apod, dispatch} = useContext(NasaContext)
  const loaded = useRef(false);
  const {title, url, explanation} = apod

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({type: 'SET_LOADING'})
    const loadApod = async() => {
      const apodData = await getApod()
      loaded.current = true;
      dispatch({type: 'SET_APOD', payload: apodData})
    }
    loadApod()
  }, [dispatch])

  if (!loaded.current) { return <Spinner /> }
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{title}</h2>
      <img src={url} className='apod' alt='apod'/>
      <p>{explanation}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Apod;
```

Comment: I tried like this and some variations but now I'm getting an infinite spinner.

Comment: did you reach the `loaded.current = true;` statement ? I moved it just before the call to dipatch function

Comment: I made a mistake, you cannot pass `async` function to `useEffect` hook. I rewrote the function like you did in your example

Comment: if you put `loaded.current = true;` statement before calling the dispatch function, it doesn't work ?

Comment: Your answer is working. It's my first week with react, this was very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had an idea, to clean the object in Context using onClick on the navbar button.
Is this the best way? I don't know but it's working as I wanted.

```
import NasaContext from '../../context/nasa/NasaContext'
import { useContext } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import logo from './assets/logo.png'


function Navbar() {
  const {dispatch} = useContext(NasaContext)
  const resetApod = () => {
    const pathname = window.location.pathname
    if ( pathname !== '/' ) {
      dispatch({type: 'SET_APOD', payload: {}})
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className="navbar">
      <div className="navbar-logo">
        <img src={logo} alt='Experimentum'/>
      </div>
      <div className="navbar-menu">
        <Link to='/' onClick={resetApod}>APOD </Link>
        <Link to='/about'>ABOUT </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

Comment: It works, but Olivier's answer is better.